# JavaAgents in @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, testing, gradle

How can I add `javaagents` to my `@SpringBootTest` instance? To the production instance, I successfully set but I cant do the same with the test instances.

And I got the following warnings/errors:

```
-Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [..] for the entity class [class ... since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

My `build.gradle.kts`

```
val springInstrument: Configuration by configurations.creating
val eclipseLink: Configuration by configurations.creating

dependencies {
...
    eclipseLink("org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.7.5")
    springInstrument("org.springframework:spring-instrument:5.2.2.RELEASE")
...
}

    val bootRun by getting(BootRun::class) {
        jvmArgs = mutableListOf(
                "-javaagent:${configurations.getByName("springInstrument").asPath}",
                "-javaagent:${configurations.getByName("eclipseLink").asPath.substringBefore(":")}"
        )
    }
```